# IPhone Frozen basic reset not working

Tags: ios, iphone

My iPhone has frozen on the slide to unlock screen.

I cannot turn it off or reset it.

The device turns off every minute and restarts to change the time.

Is there a way to stop it?

I have tried to restore using iTunes and this message pops up,

[image]

I have gone through the '[more information](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1275)' on the apple website

Comment: Have you tried holding both the power and home buttons for several seconds until you see the Apple logo?

Comment: yes, I cannot turn it off or reset it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug it in to USB power or a mac and hold the home button as it enters the reboot cycle. It should show the dock connector and iTunes screen. From there you don't need to restore the device (erasing everything) but can connect to iTunes and try powering off and rebooting with it connected to the iTunes can often help break out of a minor software issue.

---

Update added to most appropriate answer.

I went to the Apple store and they were able to run diagnostics on the phone, from there they were able to restore.

Comment: Thanks @bmike I have tried this, and the dock connector icon did not appear, it just started up as usual. I Have let the battery drain and powered up, and still the same issue. Just doing a restore (which I didn't want to do, as there is stuff on there which is not backed up).

Comment: Ugh - I hope the home button isn't broken - even in the tightest of reboot loops, when you just hold the home button and the 30 pin connector has power / connectivity - it should hit the firmware and interrupt the OS boot process. Keep us posted - this might be an edge case where we learn something about the hardware ...

Comment: the home button isn't broken, it was working fine when it froze for the first time, I have updated the question, with further information

Answer (score -1):

Had the solution for my problem from www.sarnatconsulting.be , read the article in the info tab. Worked well.

The solution is to connect your device to another PCM with a fresh installation of iTunes and reproces the IOS 6 import. After the you can continue the restore of the apps on the old pc

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.